# How to get data from a table between date and time range

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table call PAYMENT_DET with the fields PAYMENT_DATE DATE, PAYMENT_TIME VARCHAR2 and its data is as shown below where date format is MM/DD/YYYY

PAYMENT_DATE       PAYMENT_TIME
2/13/2017          13:03:59
2/13/2017          14:03:59
2/14/2017          01:03:59
2/14/2017          04:03:00

My requirement is, I have two input dates like from date with time and To Date with time. Between the given inputs range i want get details from the above table.

Please suggest me query for this.

Comment: can you provide the input range samples? It will help to form query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple example to help you out. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 1 col1, '02/13/2017' col2, '13:03:59' col3 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 col1, '02/13/2017' col2, '14:03:59' col3 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 col1, '02/14/2017' col2, '01:03:59' col3 FROM dual
  )a
WHERE to_date(a.col2
  ||' '
  ||col3,'mM/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2017 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE('01/01/2018 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```